# Facebook doesn't scraped html correctly

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am just trying to load my html using link on facebook,but it is not going to render my html correctly. It is rendering only meta graph tags, which is mentionted by facebook below

```
<meta property="og:title" content="HyperArts SEO Services" />

<meta property="og:type" content="website" />

<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.hyperarts.com/_img-fb/Image-SRC_HyperArts.png" />

<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.hyperarts.com/_img-fb/Image-SRC_HyperArts_blue.png" />

<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.hyperarts.com/seo-services/search-engine-optimization-services-san-francisco.html" />

<meta property="og:site_name" content="HyperArts Web Design & Social Media" /><!--formatted---
```

My html is

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myapp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/din-Regular.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="myapp" />
    <title>myapp</title>
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="profileController.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="wraper"></div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="profile-box-row clearfix">
            <div class="user-profile left">
                <div class="imgb">
                    <div class="imgb-in">
                        <img src="images/img_man.jpg" alt="img">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="user-name">Akshay</span>
            </div>
            <div class="txtb">
                <span class="percent">80%</span>
                <p>common interests in myapp</p>
            </div>
            <div class="user-profile right">
                <div class="imgb">
                    <div class="imgb-in">
                        <img src="images/img_girl.jpg" alt="img">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="user-name">Pratiksha</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="botom-text">
            <p>See who tops to match your preferences among friends. Download Samepinchh http: //<a href="www.myapp.com" target="_blank">www.myapp.com</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It is not going to render anything inside body tag,only showing title and image in head tag.

Below is a my controller which i am using for share html link.

My controller

```
public void shareMatchingOnFb(final User user, final Long friendId, final String fbAccessToken) {

        FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(fbAccessToken);
        InputStream is;

        FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message",
                "Testing"),Parameter.with("link",
                "http://example.com/122222/1222212"));
    }
```

Please help me what i am doing wrong there,i have already spend one day on it.

Thanks

Comment: So, why aren't you adding the mentioned meta-tags to the head of the page?

Comment: I mentioned title tag and it is displaying. But inside body tag,it doesn't render anything,i am asking for this.

Comment: It shouldn't render anything in the body tags. It's META content

Answer (score 0):

Add the meta-tags to the head on your HTML

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

The most important ones are title, description and image

Note: after you make changes, you have to tell Facebook to scrape the updated content: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: Is there any way one can show webpage html in facebook share.

Comment: I want to share a matching of two users from my app whose photos and matching percent will be in that html page.

Comment: that makes no sense to me, please explain what you are trying to do. Perhaps show your controller.

Comment: Please see the updated question,i have added controller code.